# Являлось выявление

Tags: стилистика

"Задачей первого этапа эксперимента **являлось выявление** у испытуемых ...".
Употребление клишированного "являлось выявление" - речевая ошибка? 
Как тогда можно иначе сформулировать? Торможу что-то.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Являлось выявление" - это тавтология (греч. tauto — тот же, logos — слово), повторение однокоренных слов или морфем в пределах одного текста, одной фразы, одного словосочетания . Примеры типичных для официальной речи тавтологий: польза от использования, явление проявляется.

Возможная замена: "Задачей первого этапа эксперимента являлось обнаружение у испытуемых ...".

Comment: Не согласна. Тавтология - именно избыточное употребление, то есть если одно из слов спокойно можно выкинуть, не потеряв при этом смысла (обернуться назад, бежать бегом, идти пешком).
А тут все нормально с технической точки зрения. Просто звучит не очень гармонично.

Comment: Для Кристабел. Избыточное употребление - это плеоназм. В данном предложении "являлось выявление" - это тавтология, то есть употребление однокоренных слов

Answer (score 2):

"Задачей первого этапа эксперимента **было** выявление у испытуемых ..." Хотя для научного стиля такая тавтология по-моему вполне допустима.

Answer (score 1):

София права, это тавтология.  Избыточное употребление - это плеоназм. См. здесь. http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=8.23